# if $()=+2^2\sin(\frac{1}{}) $ and $′()=1−2\cos(\frac{1}{})+4x\sin(\frac{1}{})$ how to proof that $′(0)=1.$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

my first idea is : take a $=\frac{1}{}$ then (if →0 then →∞) hence $\lim_{→0}{1−2\cos(\frac{1}{})+4\sin(\frac{1}{})}=\lim_{→∞}1−2\cos−\frac{1}{}\sin =\lim_{→∞}1−\frac{2}{}\cos −\frac{1}{}\sin $. So $\frac{1}{}\sin →0$, because $\sin $ is bounded and $\frac{1}{}→0$, I don't know what to do for the other term, other idea is to use $\sin(\frac{1}{}+)=\sin(\frac{1}{})\cos()+\cos(\frac{1}{})\sin  $, but I don't know if it is work (I'm trying but don't go anyplace), besides I will try to dominate by other function, I hope somebody can help me please. Thanks.
Observation: I found this in wikipedia, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem when its wrote counter-example, and I don't understand this example.

Comment: Write the question into the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the definition of derivative. $f'(0)=\lim_{ x \to 0} \frac {f(x)-f(0)} x=\lim_{ x \to 0} [1+2x\sin (\frac   1 x)]=1$ since $\sin (\frac  1x )$ is bounded.

Comment: thank you Kavi Rama Murthy